# Is there a grid system (much like that offered by Bootstrap) that accompanies google material components?

Tags: material-design, material-components

I'm implementing [material-components-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) into a web application and was wondering: is there is a grid system that integrates with the library of components? Material-components is developed by a team of designers and developers at Google, and I imagine there should be a way to implement a grid system with out having to drop in Bootstrap (which would redundantly include another set of UI components into my repository).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [layout-grid](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-layout-grid) ([demo](https://material-components-web.appspot.com/layout-grid.html)) is the component you're looking for.